# Find three numbers that can be consecutive terms of geometric sequence and first, second and seventh term of arithmetic sequence and whose sum is $93$

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

Three numbers that are consecutive terms of geometric sequence summed up equal to $93$.
$$b_k+b_{k+1}+b_{k+2}=93$$
Those same numbers are the first, the second and the seventh term of arithmetic sequence.
$$a_1=b_k,a_2=b_{k+1},a_7=b_{k+2}$$
Can someone help me determine what those terms are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:*
We have $b_k = a$, $b_{k+1}=a+t$, $b_{k+2}=a+6t$ and so
$$
3a+7t = 93
$$
Since $b_k,b_{k+1},b_{k+2}$ are consecutive terms of a geometric sequence, we have $b_{k+1}^2 = b_{k}b_{k+2}$ and so
$$
(a+t)^2 = a(a+6t) 
$$

Comment: I give up! I really don't know how to continue.

Comment: @Hanlon, the second equation gives $t=0$ or $t=4a$.

Comment: How? Can you explain how do you go from $b^2_{k+1}$ to $b_kb_{k+2}$?

Comment: I understand that, but I still don't understand why is $b^2_{k+1}$ equal to $b_kb_{k+2}$. In other words, I don't understand what does that they are consecutive has to do with that inference.

Comment: @Hanlon, $b_{k+1}=b_k r, b_{k+2}=b_k r^2$.

Comment: Do we get $t^2-4t=0$? Solving that I get $t \in \{0,4\}$, but this is different from yours $t \in \{0,4a\}$

Comment: For $t=4$ I get that $a=65/3$, and I don't think that's correct. $t=0$ is fine, I get $a=31$.

Comment: Sorry, it should be $t^2-4ta=0$. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Let the three terms be $a,b, c$.

Hence we have

$$\begin{align}
a&=a&&=a\\
b&=ar&&=a+d\\
c&=ar^2&&=a+7d\\\\
b-a&=a(r-1)&&=d\tag{1}\\
c-a&=a(r^2-1)=a(r-1)(r+1)&&=6d\tag{2}\\
\text{Putting $(1)$ into $(2)$}:\qquad \\
&\qquad d(r+1)&&=6d\\
&\qquad  d(r-5)&&=0\\
&\qquad d=0 \qquad \text{or}&& r=5
\end{align}$$
If $\boxed{r=5}$, then
$$ a(1+5+5^2)=93\\
 \color{}{\qquad \lbrace a,b,c\rbrace}=\color{red}{\lbrace 3,15, 75 \rbrace}
$$

If $\boxed{d=0}$, then all three terms are equal, i.e. 
$$\lbrace a,b,c\rbrace=\color{red}{\lbrace31,31,31\rbrace}$$

Comment: $\langle3,15,75\rangle$ is only one solution. The second one is $\langle31,31,31\rangle$.

Comment: When you canceled $r-1$ after Dividing gives: you lost the solution $r=1$

Comment: I have the solution here with me and both $\langle3,15,75\rangle$ and $\langle31,31,31\rangle$ are listed.

Comment: Solution edited to include the obvious trivial case with all equal terms.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, note that:
$$\begin{align}\frac{\frac{\frac{a_1+a_7}{2}+a_2}{2}+a_1}{2}&=a_2 \Rightarrow\\ \frac{\frac{a_1+a_7+2a_2}{4}+a_1}{2}&=a_2 \Rightarrow \\
a_1+a_7+2a_2+4a_1&=8a_2 \Rightarrow \\
a_7-6a_2+5a_1&=0 \Rightarrow \\
b_kq^2-6b_kq+5b_k&=0 \Rightarrow  \\
q^2-6q+5&=0 \Rightarrow \\
q_1=1, q_2=5.\end{align}$$
Hence:
$$b_k(1+q+q^2)=93 \Rightarrow \\
b_k=\frac{93}{1+1+1^2}=\color{blue}{31}; b_{k+1}=31\cdot 1=\color{blue}{31}; b_{k+2}=31\cdot 1^2=\color{blue}{31};\\
b_k=\frac{93}{1+5+5^2}=\color{red}{3}; b_{k+1}=3\cdot 5=\color{red}{15}; b_{k+2}=3\cdot 5^2=\color{red}{75}.$$